# cache a DOM element inside an instantaneus function with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, caching

I have an instantaneus function, and when I try to have a globally cached DOM object, retrieving it with JQuery, inside the instantaneous function, something weird happens.

The `appendMessage` function does not append the message the the `domObject`, but, if I call the dom object (instead of caching it), then the message is appended to the dom object.

I have no idea on why is this happening. ¿does JQuery destroys the dom object i have inside my instantaneous function? ¿how do I correctly cache this DOM  element with JQuery?

```
var foo = ( function () {
    var domObject = $( '.someDiv' );

    var appendMessage = function (message) {
        domObject.append(message);
    };

    return {
        appendMessage : appendMessage
    };

})();

$( document ).ready(function () {
    foo.appendMessage('all your base');
    $( '.someDiv' ).append('are belong to us!');

    // the html of <div class="someDiv"> will be "are belong to us!"
});
```

EDIT: here is the html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>var a DOM object into a closure</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
     </head>

     <body>

       <div class="someDiv">  </div>

     </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I'm not getting the result that you mention in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/w7muv780/

Comment: Is this javascript loaded before the HTML?

Comment: @Malk yes, it is loaded into the head tag. I just edited my question to add the html code.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I looked at the fiddle... it is weird, I am using google chrome, it only shows "are belong to us!"... maybe i am missing something on the html? o_O

Comment: @Bengalaa then, what you actually meant is "no", the div is in the html tag and i'm executing my code too early. you need to move the $("selector") part into a callback that doesn't get executed until the dom is ready. **Is there a canonical duplicate for this yet? it gets asked hundreds of times a day**

Comment: @KevinB I saw my error... thanks a lot! can you submit an answer, so I can mark it as accepted?